# Setup development environment Magento2 on local mac error

Tags: 503

To install Magento2 on my mac local, I installed php, httpd, mysql, etc via brew.
I got success message when I run bin/magento setup:install ~.
but I get 503 error when I visit local/magento_test. and endless loading on magenot-test.local

'503 Service Unavailable The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.'

/opt/homebrew/var/log/php-fpm.log

```
unable to set listen address as it's already used in another pool 'magento'
ERROR: [pool www] unable to set listen address as it's already used in another pool 'magento'
ERROR: failed to post process the configuration
ERROR: failed to post process the configuration
ERROR: FPM initialization failed
ERROR: FPM initialization failed
```

system.log is not created on var/log

/opt/homebrew/etc/httpd/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerName magento-test.local
    DocumentRoot "/Users/yohan/Development/magento_test"

    <Directory "/Users/yohan/Development/magento_test">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog "/opt/homebrew/var/log/httpd/magento_test-error_log"
    CustomLog "/opt/homebrew/var/log/httpd/magento_test-access_log" common

    <FilesMatch \.php$>
        SetHandler "proxy:unix:/opt/homebrew/var/run/php/magento-php-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost"
    </FilesMatch>
</VirtualHost>
```

/opt/homebrew/etc/php/8.1/php-fpm.d/magento.conf

```
[magento]
user = _www
group = _www
listen = /Users/yohan/php-sockets/php8.1-fpm.sock
listen.owner = yohan
listen.group = staff
listen.mode = 0660
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 50
pm.start_servers = 5
pm.min_spare_servers = 5
pm.max_spare_servers = 35
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to setup Magento 2 environment on Mac, I suggest you use Docker instead.
There are 2 most popular Docker configurations that support you setup Magento environment on Mac (and Linux, Windows - WSL) easily:

- Docker-magento (Mark Shust's Docker Configuration for Magento): https://github.com/markshust/docker-magento.
  There is a free screencast course provide details the basic usage of that docker configuration https://m.academy/courses/set-up-magento-2-development-environment-docker
- Warden: https://warden.dev/. Documentations: https://docs.warden.dev/index.html

Comment: If you had any problems when using one of these docker configurations, please let me know, I'll help.

Comment: Agreed. I should use Docker. I will try it. Thank you again, Tu Van! :)

Comment: You're welcome Yohan!